# Use custom checks in the Palantir Foundry transform decorator

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

I can specify checks in the transform decorator, such as Primary Key. Can I also specify a custom check which applies a lambda function, for example? Thanks!

I read the documentation and couldn't find an existing check type that confirms to my use case.

EDIT:
Here's a code example of what I am trying to accomplish. For example, I want to check if an array column only contains distinct elements. The transform check should raise a warning if my UDF returns false. This is how I would implement the check with an extra column (rather than using checks):

```py
    df = (
        df
        .withColumn('my_array_col1', F.array(F.lit('first'), F.lit('second'), F.lit('third')))
        .withColumn('my_array_col2', F.array(F.lit('first'), F.lit('first')))
        .withColumn('custom_check1', check_for_distinct_array_elements(F.col('my_array_col1')))
        .withColumn('custom_check2', check_for_distinct_array_elements(F.col('my_array_col2')))
    )

@F.udf
def check_for_distinct_array_elements(arr):
    return len(set(arr)) == len(arr)
```

Comment: can you write a code example of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I added a code example to the post. @fmsf, but, as I said, I would like to do this as a check (i.e., I mean the Output() parameter) rather than by adding additional columns to the dataset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create custom checks, here is an example given your described issue. I just extend the `_SizeExpectation` expectation to change how the value to check is computed, and add the `eq` function in order to work around the expectation-factory step.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from transforms.api import transform_df, Input, Output

from pyspark.sql import Column
from pyspark.sql import types as T

from transforms.expectations.utils._expectation_utils import check_columns_exist, check_column_type
from transforms.expectations.evaluator import EvaluationTarget
from transforms.expectations.column._column_expectation import _SizeExpectation
from transforms.api import Check
import operator


class CountDuplicatesExpectation(_SizeExpectation):

    def __init__(self, col, op=None, threshold=None):
        super(CountDuplicatesExpectation, self).__init__(col, op, threshold)
        self._col = col
        self._op = op
        self._threshold = threshold

    @check_columns_exist
    @check_column_type([T.ArrayType], lambda self: self._col)
    def value(self, target: EvaluationTarget) -> Column:
        return F.size(self._col) - F.size(F.array_distinct(self._col))

    def eq(self, target):
        return CountDuplicatesExpectation(self._col, operator.eq, target)


@transform_df(
    Output(
        "<output-rid>",
        checks=[
            Check(CountDuplicatesExpectation('values').eq(0), 'custom check', 'WARN'),
        ]
    ),
...
```